# Is there a way to have lambdas server files?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I really would like to use lambda functions opposed to an ec2 instance to host my website. However, I cannot figure out how to serve files (such as js files, html files, css files, images, etc.) as a response to a GET request.

Basically, I want the lambda function to serve the the html, client side js, and css when they visit the API Gateway URL

In testing with localhost (without using lambda functions) this would be my code to serve the html file on request (very basic for demonstration)

```html
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const httpServer = http.createServer((req,res) => {

    fs.readFile(/index.html, null, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.write('File not found')
        }else{
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end();
    })

})
httpServer.listen(3000);
```

I understand that lambda functions are stateless, so the part I'm concerned about in the code above is the fs.readFile(). Where do you store files with lambda functions? And how to you call fs.readFile() on these files and return the data as a response?

Comment: Where do you think the source code is stored in a lambda? Lambdas have a 500MB filesystem, bundle the files alongside the source code.

Comment: Go through this AWS documentation, I think will help you implement what wanting to do and if you get stuck ask specific question and we'll be here to help,  https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/

Comment: You need to rearchitext - S3 is for static file hosting, not Lambda. You have a static website which then makes calls to Lambda faced with API Gateway (massively oversimplified). You can’t just go from instances to instance-less by copying and pasting code.

Comment: I’m just considering abandoning lambda functions and going with the ec2 instance. That way I don’t have to use amplify, lambda, dynamodb, s3 and redesign me entire program.

Comment: The standard way of solving this is to use S3 to host the static site and CloudFront for caching them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started-secure-static-website-cloudformation-template.html